# The set of all real numbers $\epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < 1$ is equinumerous with the set of all sets of positive integers

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How is a proof like this normally conducted? I know that Cantor's theorem may prove useful here, but I'm having trouble extending the definition to problems that are (seemingly) unrelated.

Comment: The problem says exactly what I typed: Show that the set of real numbers $\epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < 1$ is equinumerous with the set of all sets of positive integers.

Comment: My bad, I read only one instance of "set".

Comment: Consider the set of bit strings representing the numbers $x\in(0,1)$ and consider the mapping which takes a subset $A\subseteq \Bbb N$ and maps it to the sum $\sum_{a\in A} 2^{-a}$ which is a real number within the interval $[0,1)$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Write any number between $0$ and $1$ as a binary "decimal" and consider the map
$$\phi(\epsilon)=\{\,k\mid\hbox{the $k$th binary digit of $\epsilon$ is $1$}\,\}\ .$$
There are problems with this arising from the fact that, for example,
$$0.10000000\cdots=0.01111111\cdots\ ;$$
see if you can make the basic idea work.